# React DropDown Menu Task

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am at very beginner level and I 'm stuck on this task.

**Tasks**

1. When the page loads, populate a dropdown menu with the results from a GET call to https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/
2. When a country is selected from the country dropdown, populate a second dropdown with the results from a GET call to https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/<country_code>/states/

I can not get data from second API for states.

Thank you for your time...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CountriesStates = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                //console.log(data);
                setCountries(data); 
            })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        if(countries === 'default' || countries === '') {
            setStates([]);
        } else {
            fetch(`https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/${countries}/states/`)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    setStates(data);
                })
            }   
    }, [countries]);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <select name='countries' id='countries' style={{backgroundColor:'lightblue', borderRadius:'5px', fontSize:'1.3rem', marginRight:'3rem'}}>
                {
                    countries.map((country) => (                    
                            <option key={country.id}>{country.name}</option>                   
                    ))
                }
                </select>         
            </div>

            <div>
                <select name='states' id='states' style={{backgroundColor:'lightblue', borderRadius:'5px', fontSize:'1.3rem', marginRight:'3rem'}}>
                {
                    states.map((state) => (                    
                            <option key={state.id}>{state.name}</option>                   
                    ))
                }
                </select>         
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CountriesStates;
```

Comment: You are sending all the country state as the API parameter `country_code`. However, you need to use the selected country's code there. You can try `countries[0].code` to test. For example, the first country is `Australia` and its code is `AU`. Then when you send a request to the URL with these parameters: https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/AU/states, it returns as you expected. Hope, it's clear

Comment: @OnurDoğan thank you so much it really helped. when I check it with `countries[0].code` yes I can see states on second dropdown. Bu I should study more to understand the logic and how to do it I guess.

Comment: Glad to be helpful to you. As a suggestion, you can create a new state like `selectedCountry` and then set it when selecting a country from the first (countries) dropdown. Also, need to change the second `useEffect`s dependency to `selectedCountry` instead of the `countries`. Then it will be triggered whenever you change `selectedCountry` and will fetch states for the selected country. It might be a bit complicated to explain, so I will post an answer to explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the selected country, need to add a new state to store and update it. I added the `selectedCountry` state and then set it whenever the selected option is changed from the dropdown.
Then, need to fetch states whenever the selected country is selected. For this, need to use `selectedCountry` instead of `countries` in the `useEffect` dependency that fetches the states.

**CountriesStates.js**: (Added some comment lines)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CountriesStates = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
    // Store the selected country in a new state
    const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setCountries(data); 
                // set the first country as selected automatically 
                setSelectedCountry(data[0]);
            })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // If there's no selected country, then prevent sending an API request and clear the states
        if (!selectedCountry) {
           setStates([]);
           return;
        }

        fetch(`https://xc-countries-api.fly.dev/api/countries/${selectedCountry.code}/states/`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(setStates);
}   
    }, [selectedCountry]); // This useEffect should be rendered whenever the selected country is changed

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <select 
                    name='countries' 
                    id='countries' 
                    style={{backgroundColor:'lightblue', borderRadius:'5px', fontSize:'1.3rem', marginRight:'3rem'}}
                    onChange={event => setSelectedCountry(countries.find(({ id }) => id.toString() === event.target.value.toString()))}>
                {
                    countries.map((country) => (
                         <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>{country.name}</option>                   
                    ))
                }
                </select>         
            </div>
           {!!states.length &&
              <div>
                  <select name='states' id='states' style={{backgroundColor:'lightblue', borderRadius:'5px', fontSize:'1.3rem', marginRight:'3rem'}}>
                  {
                      states.map((state) => (                    
                              <option key={state.id}>{state.name}</option>                   
                      ))
                  }
                  </select>         
              </div>
           }
        </>
    );
};

export default CountriesStates;
```

I also created a [DEMO LINK](https://playcode.io/1766357) to review and test it easily.

Hope, it's clear and helpful.

Comment: this is so helpful and with that comments which you add helped me to understand why exactly you used codes and what was it for. I am grateful for your help!!

Comment: I am so glad to be helpful. You're welcome!